grpc 1.62 performance regression compared with 1.55
Recently, we are performing performance test on gRPC server receiving unary RPC request. We are performing the test on a 48 core server machine with CPU E5-2650 2.20gHZ. We see that after we upgrade the grpc version from 1.55 to 1.62, we see a performance drop pretty large:

We followed the qps way to implement the server, and the client will send unary rpc on a fix interval. we check the RPC response time for all the unary requests. See code here:
perf test repo
The throughput for grpc 1.62 should be similar to that of grpc 1.55 (with default-executor). But there is about 20% throughput drop compared with grpc 1.55 (with default-executor). Why there is a large performance drop when the server is saturated on grpc 1.55?
P.S. The table for the result of 1.55 and 1.62:



RPS
1.55
1.62




10000
40003
40004


15000
58129
57065


20000
76865
60719


25000
56703
58914


30000
45976
61084


40000
50060
61025




Can you share a table of the performance results? The chart is a little unclear. Are the results consistent? How many times have you run them?

Hi @rutgersmike, I have edit the question and update the RPS result. To your questions, the result of grpc 1.55 is not stable: sometimes its performance is quite worse (like in the table) and some times it can keep at 75k RPS. For 1.62, the result is quite stable. I have runed the test about 1min per round.

Hi. I responded to your post on grpc-io. Please open a bug on GitHub.
